# DB updates but Vuex store does not

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to submit a form that updates a user's account settings. The form submits correctly to my API and the database entry updates. The component updates correctly initially, but when I refresh the page the component reverts back to its initial state, telling me that the Vuex store hasn't updated correctly (I think?)

I'm sure it's my ignorance on Vuex in general but I also feel that I'm pretty close. I'm basing this off of Jason Watmore's excellent posts, [this one](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/07/14/vue-vuex-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example) specifically. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

**ProfilePage.vue (parent component)**

```
<template>

    <div class='profile-container'>

      ...

      <!-- {/* User Info */} -->
      <div class='user-info-container'>
        <h1 class='user-headline'>{{ account.user | prettyName }}</h1>
        <p>{{ account.user | userLocation }}</p>
      </div>

      <!-- {/* Personal Details Form */} -->
      <div class='personal-details' v-if='activeSelection(0)' >
        <personal-form :account='this.account.user' v-on:listensubmit='handleSubmit'/> 
      </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import PersonalForm from './_partials/PersonalForm';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    tile         : false,
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      account: state => state.account
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('account', ['update']),
    handleSubmit: function(user) {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          this.submitted = true;
          this.update(user);
        }
      });
    },
  },
  components: {
    PersonalForm,
  }
};
</script>
```

**PersonalForm.vue (child component)**

```
<template>
  <v-form ref="personal-details-form" lazy-validation>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <!-- First Name -->
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="user.firstName"
            label="First Name"
            color="primary"
            prepend-inner-icon="playlist_add"
            outline
          />
        </v-flex>

        <!-- Last Name -->
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="user.lastName"
            label="Last Name"
            color="primary"
            prepend-inner-icon="playlist_add"
            outline
          />
        </v-flex>

        <!-- Email -->
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <v-text-field
            v-model='user.email'
            v-validate="'required|email'"
            :error-messages="errors.collect('email')"
            label='E-mail'
            data-vv-name='email'
            color='primary'
            outline
            prepend-inner-icon="mail_outline"
          />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout justify-end>
        <v-btn @click="handleSubmit" color="primary" :ripple="false">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    submitted    : false,
  }),
  computed: {
    user () {
      return {...this.account}
    }
  },
  props: {
    account: {
      type    : Object,
      required: true,
    },
    listensubmit: {
      type: Function,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit(event) {
      this.$emit('listensubmit', this.user);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**account.module.js**

```
import { userService } from '../_services';
import { router } from '../_helpers';

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const state = user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: {}, user: null };

const actions = {
update({ dispatch, commit }, user) {
    commit('updateRequest', user);

    userService.update(user)
      .then(
        u => {
          commit('updateSuccess', user);
          dispatch('alert/success', 'Account updated', { root: true })
        },
        error => {
          commit('updateFailure', error);
          dispatch('alert/error', error, { root: true });
        }
      );
  },
}

const mutations = {
updateRequest(state, user) {
    state.status = { updating: true };
  },
  updateSuccess(state, user) {
    state.status = { updated: true };
    state.user = user;
  },
  updateFailure(state) {
    state.status = { updated: false };
  }
}

export const account = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

**user.service.js**

```
import config from 'config';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';

export const userService = {
  update,
};

function update(user) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  };

  return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${user.id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.text().then(text => {
      const data = text && JSON.parse(text);

      if (!response.ok) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
              // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
              logout();
              location.reload(true);
          }

          const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
          return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      return data;
  });
}
```

Comment: How does your store get its initial data from the database?

Comment: On login, I return a JWT from my API along with user information, and the user object is stored in local storage. At the top of the account.module.js file, you'll see where state is being set based on whether the user is logged in or not. (I hope that's what you were asking, apologies for my rookie-ness showing)

Comment: Ah, I see. You would need to update your `localStorage` entry too so it's up-to-date when you reload

Comment: I was thinking that too. This might be off-topic, but is it fairly normal to keep a user object in localStorage?

Comment: As @Phil said, you will need to set your localStorage or you won't get anything from it. I don't see where you do that. Also, you may have a typo here: ```{ status: { loggedIn: true }, user }```. Should that be ```{ status: { loggedIn: true }, user: user }```?

Comment: To comment on your off topic question and storing a user in localStorage, I would suggest not, If you have a JWT then you would normally use it to authenticate again with each page reload.

Comment: @CUGreen `{ user }` is the same as `{ user: user }`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Answer (score 0):

Per Phil's help in the comments of the original question, updating the user object in localStorage seems to have solved the problem.